# Cant see the scrollbar color or scrollable 'thin

Tags: html, css

```css
.poem {
  overflow: scroll;
  scrollbar-color: red orange;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  white-space: wrap;
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<p class="poem">abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz
  abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz
  abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz </p>
```

As per [MDN-Scrollable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scrollbars#scrollbar_styling_in_action) Link I can't see the thin scrollbar with a red thumb and an orange track so in my EDGE Version 113 browser I tried out the code snippet, but I can't see the `thin scrollbar with a red thumb and an orange track` in my EDGE Browser also. Please help my code error if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to style the scrollbar of the element. Try this:-

```css
.poem {
  overflow: scroll;
  white-space: wrap;
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
}

.poem::-webkit-scrollbar{
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
}

.poem::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
  background-color: red; 
}

.poem::-webkit-scrollbar-track{background-color: orange;}
```

```html
<p class="poem">abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz
  abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz
  abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghjkilmopqrstuvwxyz </p>
```

According to the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar):-

"::-webkit-scrollbar is only available in Blink- and WebKit-based browsers"

You can see **::-webkit-scrollbar** has good browser support:-

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar#browser_compatibility

For **scrollbar-color**, the browser support is poor:-

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-color#browser_compatibility

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: i see a note in developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Webkit_Extensions as Note: Avoid using on websites. These properties will only work in WebKit applications.so is it ok to use webkit?

Comment: The property scrollbar-color: has very poor support. Look at the link:- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-color#browser_compatibility . While the ::-webkit has good support. Look at the link:- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar#browser_compatibility

Comment: works as expected .. great

Comment: minor addition in your answer: added track tag `.poem::-webkit-scrollbar-track{background-color: orange;}`

Answer (score 2):

You are doing everything correct, it's just that the `scrollbar-color` property is not well supported in all browsers. Basically only Firefox supports this.  Open this question in Firefox and your demo works as expected.

You can check out the browser support for this property on this page at the bottom: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-color

Comment: for MS Edge browser ,how to write code then to see scrollbar colors?

Comment: Just google that, it's literally the first result.  Basically you just need to use the `-webkit-` prefix.  See support for that here: https://caniuse.com/css-scrollbar

Comment: i see a note in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Webkit_Extensions as  Note: Avoid using on websites. These properties will only work in WebKit applications.so is it ok to use webkit?

Comment: It has poor browser support. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-color#browser_compatibility

Comment: If you want custom scrollbars in as many browsers as possible you will have to use both of these.  But even then it's not going to be supported everywhere.  But, it's also nice that it's not something super important since the default scrollbars will always appear so at least the page can always be scrolled.

Answer (score 1):

the syntax is correct it just doesnt support your browser. scrollbar-color: red orange; scrollbar-width: thin; supports only firefox. try using

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Webkit_Extensions there a note Note: Avoid using on websites. These properties will only work in WebKit applications. so shouldnt I avoid webkit then

Comment: if you are worried that it may not be visible to other browsers, find syntax applicable to all browsers or manually add other CSS properties like combining scrollbar-color: red orange; scrollbar-width: thin; (firefox) and ::-webkit-scrollbar to perform the task you wanted.